# List of Android phones with SPEC: VFP, NEON, ARMv6/7

Tags: android, arm

I am looking for online list (may be wiki) with all major android phones like:-

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_Android_devices

I would like it include technical information like VFP, VFPv3, NEON, ARMv6, ARMv7, etc

Most important is VFP (hardware float point)

According to Flurry we have 100+ device to check and I would like to understand how many devices support float point VFP.

Comment: I don't think that this is off topic. This is directly related to compiling native libraries for Android for proper compatibility.

Comment: I agree with frankish, the question is not off topic and should be re-opened.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think such list exists and since you would be interested in *majority* only Google would know which ones are used most.

However Android phones build on platforms / chipsets which groups that 100+ devices to a handful, so you should check features of those instead of individual devices.

Some more concrete info:

Majority of ARMv7 devices include VFP and from those only platform that doesn't support NEON is [nVidia Tegra2](http://wiki.debian.org/ArmHardFloatPort/VfpComparison#FPU).

ARMv6 devices like G1 doesn't support VFP.

As closing notes, I don't think such list would be useful. If an old device tries to run a new application, it should just run slower, given you've done your homework and provided compatibility.

Comment: Sometimes running slower means "broken". For example an audio decoder may need VFP to decode smoothly on armv6 devices. For example, if you run it on armv6 device without VFP, audio will be cut every 2-3 seconds. I think that list would be really helpful.

Comment: @frankish I noticed your a few posts on armv6 and Android. Problem is, there is no armv6 profile for Android. Available ARM profiles are armv5 and armv7+fp (https://android.googlesource.com/platform/ndk/+/master/docs/text/APPLICATION-MK.text). So when you are trying some hacks on armv6, you won't be getting any support from upstream development anyway.

Comment: So, do you mean that I cannot even filter out armv5 devices?

Comment: @frankish You can do that on market by not attaching only armeabi-v7a OSs and not armeabi SOs. (http://stackoverflow.com/a/17148900/1163019) But then what that has anything to do with ARMv6?

Comment: I want the app available for "ARMv6+VFP & ARMv7" but not for "ARMV5* and ARMv6"

Comment: @frankish afaik there is no such filtering on Google Play.

Comment: Maybe we can do it by requiring things those correspond to requirement of armv6 (+vfp) devices? For example requiring opengl 2.0 etc..?

Comment: @frankish no idea about that.