# Limit an android app only to armv7 devices

Tags: android, android-ndk, arm

I am now developing a game which runs fine on the ARM v7 devices, but there are problems with the ARM v6 devices. Is there a way to limit the game only for ARM v7 devices?

Comment: Maybe you can combine this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6630386/how-to-find-arm-processor-version-on-android-device with this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3054973/android-how-to-run-a-shell-command-from-within-code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you set `APP_ABI` in `Application.mk` to just produce ARM v7 (`armeabi-v7a`) compatible libraries, `Android Market` / `Google Play` should filter non ARM v7 devices from seeing your application.

```
APP_ABI := armeabi-v7a
```

If you don't have a native part in your application, you can still create a simple stub library to get filtering in the Google Play.